# Find references of your question and answers to other sites

Tags: feature-request

This may be odd, but I wanted to ask if is there any way on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) to find references of my question or answer to other sites?

I mean, when we see statistics of our sites or using [Google Analytics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics) we see how many people and from where my posts are being viewed. Let suppose I answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684527/separate-angular2-typescript-files-and-javascript-files-into-different-folder-m/37164273#37164273). This answer may seem important. It is related to Angular 2. Maybe some developer of Angular team came across this answer and he copied the link for the official documentation and pasted the link there. How would I know?

Comment: You can try using a search engine by using the URL of the question as the search query, but that only works sometimes. I agree, sometimes it would be useful to find the source of views/votes on a certain question/answer, but exposing the HTTP referrers might raise privacy concerns.